# Intersecting sets of custom variables in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This question refers to both the iOS SDK and JS API for Google Analytics.

Let's say a mobile device opens my application or views my webpage, and I want to note certain things, for example, the device's model, firmware version, and application version. It sets these as custom variables with the visitor scope.

I know I can find out how many devices of one model there are, or how many devices on one firmware version there are, but can I determine how many devices are of a specific model *and* on a specific firmware version? Or how many devices are on a specific firmware version with a certain version of my application?

I know this should technically be possible (cookies in mobile web, and UDIDs on devices), but I have not seen this anywhere and would like to confirm that it is in fact possible, and before I commit to using Google Analytics for statistic collecting. Please note, I am not looking for any other solution that can do this, there are plenty, I am asking if Google Analytics can do it in its current state. I think Google Analytics would be cool, because in order to buy my application, users have to view a webpage that I host. I could then compare the webpage's statistics to the application's statistics and gain some sort of useful data, all in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature to do this with is Advanced Segmentation.

Basically, you can create an advanced segment for the particular custom variable values you're interested in. ie, create a segment for visitors that match, say, `customVariableSlot2` value = `iPhone` AND `customVariableSlot3` value = `4`. The resulting set of visits will be the intersection of visits those 2 custom variable values.

That's the best you can do with the interface, as far as I know.

If you'd like to create a better view of this data, you can utilize the Google Analytics Export API to model the data in the views you're interested in. You can fiddle with the [Google Analytics Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) to try that with your Google Analytics data.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was there, I just didn't know where to find it. Advanced Segments seem to be all I need and more.